# Передача файлов по wifi с телефона на пк

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день. Есть задача: Написать приложение на android с телефона на пк. Гуглил на эту тему, но нашел только wifi direct. Но есть ли какой-нибудь способ обойтись без него. То есть телефон и пк подключены к сторонней wifi(не телефон раздает), человек вбивает(получает само приложение) локальный адрес компьютера и на него отправить файл. Нужны идеи , подсказки.

Comment: тысяча и один способ. От обычного использования сокетов (но тут нужно будет поработать) до поднятия на компе (который будет сервером) ftp/http сервера и на клиенте соотвественно использовать клиентские либы.

Comment: Возможно подобный способ, взаимодействие напрямую с компьютером - https://habrahabr.ru/post/301190/

Comment: @KoVadim, а без использования клиента на пк, только андроид клиент, такое возможно?

Comment: Клиент для ПК не нужен, нужен сервер. А сервер нужен, так как кто то же должен принимать файл. Другое дело, что можно использовать то, что уже есть в винде - например, ту же самбу (расшаренные папки).